# Epoxy Recos for Door Fix

Tags: repair, wood, doors, epoxy

I have an old door original to my house with a bit of rot at the top. I'm going to clean out the rot and want to use epoxy for the fill but haven't used this technique before myself and there are a lot of choices. Any recommendations on 2-part epoxy to do the job?

Answer (score 1):

This is off-topic (shopping reco), but we use Abatron or Smith's to soak/stabilize the wood. They have a fairly long cure time and penetrate well. There are quirks to the instructions that are not intuitive, so read them. Following that, we use bondo (regular or 'wood' color). Before the epoxy, try to land a good few long screws to anchor the bondo to solid wood in the door.